# Stack & queue complexity

Tags: ruby, stack, queue, complexity-theory

```
def sumarray(a)
    q = Queue.new
    for i in 0..(a.length-1)
        q.enqueue(a[i])
    end
    sum = 0
    while q.length > 0
        sum = sum + q.dequeue
    end
    return sum
end
```

Suppose that the queue implementation used in the above algorithm:

enqueue operation is O(1)
dequeue operation is O(k), where k is the number of elements currently in the queue
Taking the queue operations into account, what is the overall complexity of the above algorithm for sumarray?

Can someone explain how the complexity is derived? Thanks!

Comment: This is where I have to draw the line and say go google big O notation.  There is entirely too much information out there explaining this.  Let the google show you the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hopefully obvious that this first loop is O(n) where n=a.length

```
for i in 0..(a.length-1)
    q.enqueue(a[i])
end
```

The second loop is executing `n` times, and `q.dequeue` is O(n) so that gives us O(n<sup>2</sup>)

```
while q.length > 0
    sum = sum + q.dequeue
end
```

So the overall complexity is the worst of those which is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Now you may say that since `q` is getting smaller each iteration, this argument is over simplified. So lets sum all of the `q.dequeue` complexities.

```
O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + O(n-3) ... O(1)
```

Does this look like a sequence of triangular numbers? So we know the formula

```
n + (n-1) + (n-1) + ... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2
```

or

```
(n*n + n) / 2
```

Discarding the constant factor and the lower order complexity leaves `n*n`

Comment: I think it is a given that  you are iterating n times.  Or k times in the case of the problem.  So the dequeue is part of the iteration process.  You are still doing O(n) steps in the actual loop.  The fact that the steps in each iteration of the loop also take O(k) because the dequeue step is given to take O(k) time is what makes it go to O(k^2).  So we are doing k steps every iteration for k iterations.  This would equal k*k = k^2.  I still think he should google this to see as many examples as he needs.

Comment: My bad, I meant she needs.  Curse of being a developer.  We sometimes forget there is another sex in the human race.   Luckily, they are becoming less and less rare in the office.  A much welcomed change :).